# Start /WAIT Program.bat

Tags: process, cmd, wait

I am trying to write a batch file that starts ***another batch file***, waits for that batch file to complete its job, and then continue once that other batch file has exited. However, when I manually close the batch file launched by the first batch file, it comes up with a prompt saying:

`^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?`

Is there a way to automatically select 'N', because it needs to delete some temporary files on exit.

---

Purpose/Premise of Script: To be able to remove a flash drive and lock the station (hence copying files to external source).

Summary of Script:

1. Program Copies files to %homedrive%
2. Program launches another script (one of the files copied to homedrive)
3. After that program quits, it deletes the copied files

Solutions Tried:

- Different command switches inside of `START /WAIT +/I +/B` (Adding `/I`
  or `/B` did not produce anything useful)
- Using `/C` and `/K` switches after the `START /WAIT program.bat +/C +/K`
  (had no affect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use `echo n | program.bat` to automatically respond `n` to `^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?`, but an easy way to fool this method is to hit and keep pressed `[Ctrl]-C`.

There simply is no reliable way to disable the interruption of any program (much less a batch file). What stops the user from just closing the window?

Comment: OMG! It worked. I changed my code from start /WAIT program.bat into:
start /WAIT program.bat | echo n
works like a charm! thank you so much for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You would want a command like this:

```
start /wait program.bat|echo n>nul
```

">nul" will hide the "n" that shows up afterwards. But there doesn't seem to be a way to stop "^C" from showing up.

Comment: Seems there is a way to silence the ^C : `  start /wait program.bat 2>nul | echo n > nul`